# cases vs case_tac/induct vs induct_tac

Tags: isabelle, hol

I've been working with Isabelle/HOL for a few months now, but I've been unable to figure out the exact intention of the use of *_tac*.

Specifically, I'm talking about *cases* vs *case_tac* and *induct* vs *indut_tac* (although it would be nice to know the meaning of *tac* in general, since I'm also using other methods such as *cut_tac*).

I've noticed I can't use *cases* or *induct* using apply with ⋀-bound variables, but I can if it's an structured proof. Why?

An example of this:

```
    lemma "¬(∀x. ¬(P x)) ⟹ ∃x. P x"
  apply (rule ccontr)
  apply (erule notE)
  apply (rule allI)
  apply (case_tac "P x")
  apply (erule notE)
  apply (erule exI)
  apply assumption
  done
```

On the other hand, another difference I've noticed between *induct* and *induct_tac* is that I can use double induction with the latter, but not with the former. Again, I'm clueless why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *__tac_ are built-in tactics used in Isabelle proof scripts. I strongly suggest that you use Isabelle/Isar instead.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by using "Isabelle/Isar" instead.

Comment: I mean writing structured proofs using the Isabelle/Isar language environment. I strongly suggest you read [this tutorial on Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/prog-prove.pdf) and [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/isar-ref.pdf) for further information.

Comment: Regarding the specific issues with the use of the proof methods _cases_ and _induction_ versus the use of the tactics _case_tac_ and _induct_tac_ it would be good to see an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JavierDíaz, I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`_tac` are built-in tactics used in `apply`-scripts. In particular, `case_tac` and `induct_tac` have been basically superseded by the `cases` and `induction` proof methods in Isabelle/Isar. As you mentioned, `case_tac` and `induct_tac` can handle ⋀-bound variables. However, this is quite fragile, since their names are often generated automatically and may change when Isabelle changes (of course, you could use `rename_tac` to choose fixed names). That's one of the reasons why nowadays structured proof methods are preferred to unstructured tactic scripts. Now, back to your example: In order to be able to use `cases`, you can introduce a structured block as follows:

```
lemma "¬(∀x. ¬(P x)) ⟹ ∃x. P x"
  apply (rule ccontr)
  apply (erule notE)
  proof (intro allI)
    fix x
    assume "∄x. P x"
    then show "¬ P x"
      apply (cases "P x")
      apply (erule notE)
      apply (erule exI)
      apply assumption
      done
  qed
```

As you can see, structured proofs are typically verbose but much more readable than linear `apply`-scripts.

If you're still curious about the "double-induction" issue, an example would be very welcome. Finally, if you want to learn more about structured proofs using the Isabelle/Isar language environment, I'd strongly suggest you read [this tutorial on Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/prog-prove.pdf) and [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/isar-ref.pdf) for more detailed information.

Comment: But how to use arbritrary in induct_tac?